# IN-clause error with Spring Data JPA @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql, in-clause

I'm getting an IN OUT error when using IN-clause with Spring Data @Query.

Query:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM message m WHERE m.user = :user AND m.tags IN :tags")
List<Message> findByUserAndTags(@Param("user") User user, @Param("tags") List<Tag> tags);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2
```

IN-clause works perfectly when using Spring Data automatic queries:

```
List<Message> findByUserAndTagsIn(User user, List<Tag> tags);
```

I'm missing something when using @Query annotation?

Comment: May it be that your collection "tags" is null or empty? The query seems valid to me.

Comment: I don't think so, because trying with the automatic query findByUserAndTagsIn works perfectly.

Comment: have you tried: `@Query("SELECT m FROM message m WHERE m.user = :user AND m.tags IN (:tags)")`

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM message m LEFT JOIN m.tags t
        WHERE m.user = :user 
        AND t IN :tags")
List<Message> findByUserAndTags(@Param("user") User user, 
        @Param("tags") List<Tag> tags)
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try like this:

```
 @Query("SELECT m FROM message m WHERE m.user = ?1 AND m.tags IN ?2")
    List<Message> findByUserAndTags(User user, List<Tag> tags);
```

Comment: @amateur What value are you sending in place of tags? Update your question with the code where you call this method. May be that will help.

Comment: An ArrayList<Tag> with 3 tags: [Tag(id=100, name="tag1"), Tag(id=130, name="tag2"), Tag(id=151, tag="tag3")]

Comment: Ok then I don't see any issue here. Not sure what's wrong.